# Django rest framework serializer object from ID

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this serializer:

```
class OrderLineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="item.id")
    name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="item.name")
    price = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="item.price")
    quantity = serializers.IntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(MAXNUMBERSIZE)]
    )


    class Meta:
        model = OrderLine
        fields = ("id", "name", "price", "quantity", "sub_total")
```

and it's fine when I send data to the user but is there a way to serialize data that I receive from the API without creating another serializer.

if I receive some API request with this content

```
{id : 123, quantity : 10}
```

It doesn't get the item from the db.

is there a way to do it or I have to create a dedicated serializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Doing it was actually quite simple.
It's just about a combination of using `required=False` in the serializer fields and calling the serializer with `MySerializer(data=data, partial=True)`

Comment: But why deal with the unneccesary complexity ?

Comment: for my use case was not that complex

Answer (score 2):

I believe a dedicated serializer is the way to go, first of all you won't want the complexity of using a single serializer. And it would only take 3 lines to build a new one for your input. So just make a dedicated serializer.